# Extracting Numeric Dates from Timestamp (MS Access SQL - 2016)

Tags: sql, datetime, ms-access

I've been trying to convert a Time stamp field (example value - January 6th 2020, 12:44:37.655) into a numeric date field to allow for sorting based on a date column.

I've tried using DateTime and CDate, but keep seeing "#Error" in the NewDate column when I run the query. Any tips?

Comment: It is not crystal clear what you are trying to do. when you say numeric date what do you mean, show it by the value you want to get at output.

Comment: That is a text type field? Since Access cannot recognize that string as a valid date, expect will have to parse the parts and rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access cannot recognize that string as a valid date because of the ordinal, comma, and decimal. Have to use string manipulation functions to reconfigure to a recognizable date/time value.

If the string will always have "th", a comma, and 1 to 3 decimal places, consider:
`CDate(Replace(Replace(Left([field], InStrRev([field], ".") - 1), "th", ""), ",", ""))`
Or use DateValue() if need to drop time component.

However, I presume there will be values without decimal as well as different ordinals and that expression will fail. Following assumes HH:MM:SS will always be 8 characters:

```
SELECT *, Left([Test],InStr([Test]," ")) AS Mo, 
Val(Mid([Test],InStr([Test]," "))) AS Dy, 
Mid([Test],InStrRev([Test],",")-5,5) AS Yr, 
Mid(Test,InStrRev(Test,",")+1,9) AS Tm, 
CDate([Mo] & [Dy] & [Yr] & [Tm]) AS NewDate
FROM Table;
```

Might find it more convenient to call a custom VBA function.

```
Function ConvDate(strDte As String) As Date
Dim Mo As String, Dy As String, Yr As String, Tm As String
Mo = Left(strDte, InStr(strDte, " "))
Dy = Val(Mid(strDte, InStr(strDte, " ")))
Yr = Mid(strDte, InStrRev(strDte, ",") - 5, 5)
Tm = Mid(strDte, InStrRev(strDte, ",") + 1, 9)
ConvDate = CDate(Mo & Dy & Yr & Tm)
End Function
```

If you want to drop the time portion, don't concatenate the extracted component or use DateValue() on the returned date/time value.

Consistency in structure is critical in string manipulation. The more variation, the more complicated the code.

Comment: `January 1st` would also fail your first piece of code.

Comment: I did state `always have "th"`. However, edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for such a comprehensive response June7! You are correct that the initial CDate approach leads to errors (ex. nd). The function was effective, and the first time I've tried something like that with VBA. I tend to just write SQL queries and reference them in other SQL queries. I will definitely look more into this custom VBA function approach!

Comment: On second thought, this can be done entirely within query. See revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DateValue() function.

Thus:

```
select ID, InvoiceAmount, DateValue([InvoiceDTime]) as InvoiceDate
ORDER BY DateValue([InvoiceDTime])
```

Comment: DateValue() also errors on example string for same reasons as CDate(). It also drops time component.

Comment: But  the user does not state or suggest the value is a string, but only that they want the  time part removed. If the poster gives any more information suggesting that the column in question is not a datetime column, then yes some additional conversion would be required. However I can see nor  find anything in the post that suggests this is anything  other  then a actual datetime column. Thus datevalue() should work, and will of course resolve any sorting issues.  However to be fair, no sorting issues should have existed, so the idea that this might be a string does hold some water.

Comment: In Access, can it not be a string with ordinal, comma, decimal? I considered the example value literally since I don't see any Format parameter that can produce that structure. As well as the stated sorting issue.

Comment: It could be a string - but the information provided does not make this issue clear. Poster states he  has a date/time column data.  I do agree that sorting should not then have been a issue.  So, datevalue() does strip out the time  portion, but until we actually know the column data type, we really don't know  here. Kind of doubt it would a string/text type of column. However, if the user applied some kind of format() or attempted to fix their problem, they may have well wound up with a expression that resolves to some kind of string. I do admit we are having to 2nd guess here.